# React / Redux - Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: redux, redux-actions

I am getting this error even though I am using redux thunk. Redux store is also set up correctly (I think). I am creating a MERN app and I want to send a POST request to the backend (form submit) to create a new user. The request and response from the server are fine (checked using Postman). I just can not find where the problem is. The action creator which is causing this is :-

```
    import axios from "axios";
    export function signupUser(newuser) {
        return function (dispatch) {
            axios.post("/auth", newuser).then((res) => {
                // dispatch
                dispatch({
                    type: "ADDNEW_USER",
                    payload: res.data,
                });
            });
        };
    }

The store setup is :-

    import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
    import thunk from "redux-thunk";
    import rootReducer from "./reducers";

    const initialState = {};

    // const middleware = [thunk];

    const store = createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        compose(
            applyMiddleware(thunk),
            window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
            window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
        )
    );

    export default store;


The Signup.js component is ->
[Signup.js][1]
and the error is -> [here][2]


  [1]: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gCX3wQPt9X/
  [2]: https://imgur.com/a/6SDmydw
```

Comment: Can you show where you're calling `signupUser` ?

Comment: @markerikson https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gCX3wQPt9X/ its in this link.Check this out

Comment: You code looks like. Maybe try this? https://hastebin.com/johucegivo.xml

Comment: It is showing same error.Actions must be plain objects